# Find value from spreadsheet A in spreadsheet B and move values from A to B

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to do a VLOOKUP from file A to File B and when a match is found move values to file B.  In my understanding VLOOKUP only returns a value from B to A when a match is found.  I am looping thru excel file A and doing a VLOOKUP in excel file B.  This works fine but when a match I want to stay in file B and write values from A to B.  If no match I would like to insert the row from file A to file B.  Are there alternatives to VLOOKUP or is there any way to accomplish this with VLOOKUP?

Thanks

Tried to post a comment to nutsch comment but it did not appear to take.  If it did I would like to apologize as I hit the add comment button numerous times.

Here is my follow up.

It has to be a repeatable process.  Let me try to explain again.  I have excel file 1 and 2 with possible matches in column A.  So I plan to loop thru file 1 to try to find a match in file 2 based on the column A.  I have done this in the past with VLOOKUP.  The difference here is when I find a match I want to move the data in cols B, C, D, etc from file 1 to some corresponding cols in file 2. I would call this pushing the data from file 1 to file 2.  In the case there is no match I would then want to write the data in the current row of file 1 to the end of file 2.  File 1 is the master and is used to drive the lookup in file 2.

Comment: Do you want a solution that will work once, or a solution that will work multiple times? It seems, for the once off option, you can make do with vlookup, autofilter, and copy-paste, but if you want a repeatable solution, you should go with a macro. However, the information you've provided is too sketchy to be the base for any proper recommendation on that.

Comment: You can't comment until you've gained enough reputation. You'll be there soon.

Answer (score 0):

Do the opposite for the vlookup that transfers the data: If you need the data in file 2, put the vlookup in file 2 and use it to pull the data. You can use a formula in columns B through D of file 2 like `=iferror(vlookup($A2,[file1]sheet1!$A:$D,column(),0),"")` and then do a paste values.

For the transfer of cells, you can run the vlookup on file1, do an autofilter on #N/A values (which weren't found) and copy at the end of file2.

If you record the macro of your doing these steps and post it, I should be able to clean it up.